# Помогите с кодировкой cp1251 в utf8 node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, кодировка, iconv

Много чего уже перепробывал ничего не помогло.

```
fs.readFile(file, {
    encoding: 'utf8'
  }, function read(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    console.log(data);//�����������
    var message = iconv.encode(iconv.decode(data, "cp1251"), "utf8").toString();//эээээээээ
    var res = utf8.encode(data); ///ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï
    var str = iconv.decode(new Buffer(data), 'utf8');//�����������
  });
```

Если в файле чере нотпад++ указать переобразовать в utf8 то data отображается правильно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение:

```
fs.readFile(file, null, function read(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  var message = iconv.decode(data, "cp1251").toString();
});
```

Comment: Кажется `iconv.encode` тут лишний

Comment: Да, Вы правы...

Answer (score 0):

Вот такое решение сработало для меня:

```
const fs = require('fs');
var Iconv = require('iconv').Iconv;
var iconv = new Iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8');
const encoded = fs.readFileSync(file);
const decoded = iconv.convert(encoded).toString();
```

iconv устанавливается вот так:

```
npm install iconv
```